# Creating multiple columns in data table with a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

My data table looks like:

```
head(data)
    Date         AI   AGI      ADI   ASI   ARI   ERI   NVRI  SRI   FRI  IRI
1: 1991-09-06    NA 2094.19    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2: 1991-09-13    NA 2204.94    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3: 1991-09-20    NA 2339.10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4: 1991-09-27    NA 2387.81    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5: 1991-10-04    NA 2459.94    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6: 1991-10-11    NA 2571.07    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Don't worry about the NAs. What I want to do is make a "percentage change" column for each of the columns apart from date.

What I've done so far is:

```
names_no_date <- unique(names(data))[!unique(names(data)) %in% "Date"]

for (i in names_no_date){
      data_ch <- data[, paste0(i, "ch") := i/shift(i, n = 1, type = "lag")-1]}
```

I get the error:

```
Error in i/shift(i, n = 1, type = "lag") : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I'm wondering how I get around this error?

Comment: please be more clear, what do you mean by "percentage change" -you mean a growth function?

Comment: You 'get around it' by only passing 'numerics' into a 'binary operator'. Your `i / shift(i, ...)` is expecting numeric values as both the numerator & denominator. Maybe you need to worry about the `NA`s? And make sure you're not `lag`ging to a non-existent row.

Comment: If you're using data.table, use data.table syntax. To make a new data.table, `dt[, lapply(.SD, function(i){i / shift(i)}), .SDcols = -1]`. To add on to the existing one; `dt[, paste0(names(dt)[-1], 'ch') := lapply(.SD, function(i){i / shift(i)}), .SDcols = -1]`. And if you must use `for` loops, preallocate an object of the appropriate size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` is a string, so you are trying to divide a string in `i/shift(i, n = 1, type = "lag")`:

```
> "AI"/NA
Error in "AI"/NA : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Instead, do

```
for (i in names_no_date){
      data[, paste0(i, "ch") := get(i)/shift(get(i), n = 1, type = "lag")-1]
}
```

Also see [Referring to data.table columns by names saved in variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16617226/6455166).

---

Edit:  @Frank writes in the comments that a more concise way to produce OP's output is

```
data[, paste0(names_no_date, "_pch") := .SD/shift(.SD) - 1, .SDcols=names_no_date]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's excellent! I read the ?get help file, but i couldn't understand what it does. Do you mind explaining what get() does?

Comment: `get("x")` returns the object with the name "x" in the environment where `get` was called. For example, try `x <- rnorm(5); get("x")`.

Comment: ...that's how you `get` around this error `*ducks*`

Comment: You can also do it in one step, I guess: `data[, paste0(names_no_date, "_pch") := .SD/shift(.SD) - 1, .SDcols=names_no_date]`

Comment: Hi @Frank, I'm curious, what does the .SD mean?

Comment: Sure, it refers to the Subset of Data used in `j` of `DT[i, j]`. You can find details like this in the introductory materials for the package: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started @Gin_Salmon